# Cocoapods update error

Tags: objective-c, git, cocoapods

I pull info from github and run `pod update` and get this error:

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
Already up-to-date.
[!] The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 0.29.0 - 
Update CocoaPods, or checkout the appropriate tag in the repo.

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.4.0/lib/claide/command.rb:217:in `rescue in run': undefined method `verbose?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.4.0/lib/claide/command.rb:210:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.28.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.28.0/bin/pod:24:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

## Edit

I try `sudo gem update` this update cocoapods to 0.29. Then I run pod update and get:

```
Unable to find a specification for `cdebug`.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar issue.
Please try to uninstall `CocoaPods` and install them once more. This helped me and I hope it'd help you too!

Comment: Isn't there some update method to get newer version of CocoaPods?

Answer (score 5):

Just running Install command does update if **CocoaPods** already exists:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

No need to uninstall.

Considering **Alexander Kostiev** comment, if you want or need to uninstall older versions, you can find out what versions you have with this command:

```
gem list --local | grep cocoapods
```

The output would be something like this:

```
cocoapods (0.32.1, 0.31.1)
cocoapods-core (0.32.1, 0.31.1)
cocoapods-downloader (0.5.0, 0.4.1)
```

And remove specific one with this command:

```
gem uninstall cocoapods -v 0.31.1
gem uninstall cocoapods-core -v 0.31.1
gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader -v 0.4.1
```

Comment: if you run 
`gem list --local | grep cocoapods`
after you reinstall cocoapods as you suggested, you might see that the earlier versions of cocoapods are still on your machine